# Maclaurin polynomial estimating $\sin 15°$

Tags: power-series, taylor-expansion

I would like to know how I would determine the Maclaurin polynomial which will estimate $\sin15°$ with an error less than $10^{-4}$.

Maybe we have to use the formula $$R_n(x) = f^{(n+1)}(c) \, {(x-x_0)^{n+1}\over(n+1)!}$$ where $R_n(x)$ is the remainder of Taylor's formula.

I have no idea how to solve this question. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: First of all, transfer the angle into radians, so that you can apply the Mac-Laurin-series of $\sin(x)$

Comment: @Peter Okay, and how would I estimate it with the error less than $10^{-4}$ ? :)

Comment: I hope you approve of the edits I suggested. I feel that it makes the post a bit more legible and overall easier on the eyes.

Answer (score 2):

The Maclaurin series is $$\sin(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n\cdot x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$$

$15°$ corresponds to $x=\frac{15\pi}{180}$. Calculate $n$ such that the remainder $R_n(x)$ has absolute value smaller than $10^{-4}$. This is the point where you can truncate the Maclaurin series. Plug in $x$ into the remaining polynomial.

Comment: I forgot the factorial-sign "!", now fixed.